# Post data to an Aspen IP21 Historian

Tags: aspen

I know that it is possible to send sensors data to Aspen IP21 by using CIM-IO connected to OPC-DA servers, but I would like to send the same kind of data by using another application (that we can build in any language) which will collect data from some IoT sensors. 
Is there any method or API that I can use to communicate with IP21 without buying additional licenses from Aspen?

Answer (score 0):

it depends where in the MES you want to write.
Usually, the best way is to use the SqlPlus ODBC driver, and write queries like INSERT and UPDATE. Note that the driver need a windows platform.
Another way is to use one of the web API, like:

```
http://<serverhost>/ProcessData/samples/sample_home.html
```

Comment: Thanks! Honestly I'm not with the possibility to insert data directly into the database (specially because I don`t know the structure of the database and I'm afraid I can mess up with something). Do you have more information about the API you mentioned? Like data format and a few examples? Have you ever used it to upload process data?

Comment: I think you will some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970364/aspentech-infoplus-21-how-to-connect-and-query-data
Keep in mind that industrial data historian are not relational db, even if the Aspen Sqlplus query language looks like it.
In order to push data to ip21, you will have to learn with the aspen SqlPlus language (not the Oracle one).
You can ask your administrator for a ip_AnalogDef record to do do some tests, and search in the help file of Aspen Sqlplus (aka Aspen Sqlplus Query Writer).

Comment: As far as I understood from the link you posted, it is not possible to "send" sensors data to IP 21 using the REST API, it is only possible to query data, am I right?

Comment: You can use the webapi to post data: use the "SQL" endpoint, and write the query you want to execute. Let's say you want to use the ProcessData api: you can see what are the available feature with: http://<host>/ProcessData/samples/sample_home.html. do you see the 'SQL' item? it should be available from there: http://<host>/ProcessData/samples/Sample_SQL.aspx. And from there you will have a example of update query: check the 'non select' field. Now you can write from there your INSERT or UPDATE queries.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have no access to the server (yet), I'm trying to prepare myself for an upcoming project and would like to have some options to send the data once we are in the factory. Do you have the format of the data or any documentation so that I can prepare something in advance?

Comment: Aspen SqlPlus language is full of function to make conversion. Best you can do is call them: https://www.aspentech.com/en/products/msc/aspen-infoplus21
Also: you should contact your client because what you want to do will depend greatly on their local configuration (I'm thinking about security and firewall, mainly). One last thing: if it suits you, mark the answer as correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to move data from a PLC to a database then take a look at Node-Red. Here is a video that should help you get started. Node-Red can do OPC-UA, OPC-DA or just talk direct to the PLC with out the need for OPC in the middle it's your choice. If you need more help just ask!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaUmhhMdoyY

Node-Red can also do the GUI.

I moved a way from products like Aspen InfoPlus.21 three years ago and never looked back!!

If you need an open source visualization software for trending, charting and reporting you can use https://grafana.com/.

If you would like an open source historian or as the new buzzword is "time-series database" to log to look at https://www.timescale.com/.

Grafana and Timescale work well together!!

Comment: We already have the data available on Node-RED ( we are the developers of the , S7, PCCC, Ethernet/IP and OPC-DA nodes =D). /my problem here is to insert data into IP21. I don't know much about IP21 and that's why I post this question.

Comment: Does your company have an active support contract for IP21? If they do I would recommend talking to them first if not post-back.

Comment: No, we have no relationship with Aspen. What I want is to collect a data from a few sensors and send it to a customer's IP21 installation without using an adittional CIM-IO license

Comment: I didn't understand that to be your intent in your original question. My thought process of my original post was for you to use node-red to publish your data as a OPC server and have your historian subscribe to the data. You should look into @Madgui idea. My idea will not save you a license.

Answer (score 0):

You IoT must have any script tool to communicate/fetch the required data from it. You can use the same to push the data into IP21 which is based on SQLPlus scripting context. I am sure that this method will not require additional licences at IP21 side, assuming that you have space for additional IP21 record within your current licence, to store above data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with the help of SQLPlus script and using IP21 advanced features. Let's say data after collection form the source is saved into SQL Database (Microsoft), then there is provision given in IP21 using specific records that such record shall be executed after schedule intervals and shall get the data from source to save into IP21 tags. This requires advance scripting on SQLPlus.
Also, fetching of data from SQL DB into IP21 can also be triggered with change occurred in SQL DB (i.e. collection of new data)

Answer (score 0):

Your customer may develop a web service (SQL Plus in backend). The service should have interfacing parameters as Tagname, Value and value timestamp. You should send data to the webservice and the webservice will insert the data to IP21 in the specified tag.